# Factorizing text features for classification

Tags: python, text-classification

I  have a dataframe, df consisting of both text and numerical features similar to one shown below.

```
Feature 1     Feature 2         Feature 3           Feature 4         Label
 10            20                keyword             Human             1
  2             3                Keywords            Dog               0
  8             2                Stackoverflow       cat               0
```

Currently I convert the text features into numerical features using `factorize` function and then use the new dataframe for classification.

```
df[' Feature 3'] = df[' Feature 3'].factorize()[0]
df[' Feature 4'] = df[' Feature 4'].factorize()[0]
```

After running the above code my dataframe looks like this

```
 Feature 1     Feature 2         Feature 3           Feature 4         Label
 10            20                0                    0                 1
  2             3                1                    1                 0
  8             2                2                    2                 0
```

The `factorize` function is reading 'keywords' and 'keyword' as different words, so is there any function which will read words similar to 'keywords' and 'keyword' as same words ?

The output dataframe should actually look like this

```
 Feature 1     Feature 2         Feature 3           Feature 4         Label
 10            20                0                    0                 1
  2             3                0                    1                 0
  8             2                1                    2                 0
```

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look at stemmers.

NLTK give example on how to use them [here](http://www.nltk.org/howto/stem.html), but in short stemmers cut words down to their stem, for example...

```
from nltk.stem.porter import *

stemmer = PorterStemmer()

words = ['jog', 'jogging', 'jogged']

[stemmer.stem(word) for word in words]
```

**returns:**

```
['jog', 'jog', 'jog']
```

or for you

```
words = ['keyword', 'keywords']

[stemmer.stem(word) for word in words]
```

**returns:**

```
['keyword', 'keyword']
```

**Edit:**

I should point out that the words don't need to be similar for this to work:

```
words = ['drinking', 'running', 'walking', 'walked']
```

outputs:

```
['drink', 'run', 'walk', 'walk']
```